# How can I render values from a loop from views to template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating a private 1 to 1 chat between users and I'd like to show the last sent message, the problem is that when I'm looping every room's last message to my template it only shows me one single data and there are many.

Here is what I have in my **views.py:**

```
def my_rooms(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    room_user = Room.objects.all()

    print('----------------------------------------')
    for room in room_user:
        rooms = room.messages.all()[:1]
        print(rooms)

    return render(request, "my_room.html", {
        'rooms': rooms,
    })
```

**print(rooms)**, (each article has their own private chat room):

```
-------------------------------
[]
[<Message: 02-02-2017 09:50AM, user01 to user02 : hey>] #room1
[]
[<Message: 02-02-2017 10:52AM, user01 to user02 : Fine and you ?>] #room2
```

**my_room.html**

```
{% for room in rooms %}
    <p>{{ room.client }} : {{ room.message }}</p>
    <p>{{ room.timestamp }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

*What happens in my template ?*

I just get :

`[<Message: 02-02-2017 10:52AM, user01 to user02 : Fine and you ?>] #room2`

's datas published but NOT

`[<Message: 02-02-2017 09:50AM, user01 to user02 : hey>] #room1`

Why so ? How can I show all concerned rooms datas ?

------ UPDATE ------

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I'd like return values from the for loop to my template. I just don't understand why it's showing only 1 result and not all the `for` looped results on my template?

**models.py** might help it a bit clearer :

```
class Room(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Message(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='client', null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='seller', null=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, related_name='messages', null=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    ...
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Your code I am afraid isn't very clear and looping through all the rooms and then doing a further query for each room is going to bring your database to it's knees http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for the tip, I updated and will try to make it clearer for the next posts, I just want to render multiple objects into my template through the `for` loop, when I try it to do it like the example code above it just renders the last objects of the `for` loop.

Comment: You are redefining `rooms` in each iteration of your for loop, so it can only contain the results from the last iteration. You probably need to append them to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman's comment, who suggested me to append results to a list I could resolve this issue.

Here is how I did it :

**views.py**

```
...
    room_user = Room.objects.all()
    my_rooms = []

    for room in room_user:
        rooms = room.messages.all()[:1]
        my_rooms.append(rooms)

return render(request, "my_room.html", {
    'rooms': my_rooms,
})
```

**my_room.html**

```
{% for room in rooms %}
    {% for r in room %}
      <p>{{ r.client }} {{ r.message }}</p>
      <p>{{ r.timestamp }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the flow of your views.py code, it's only going to pass the rooms object on the last iteration of the for loop into your template. I would suggest passing `room_user` instead to the dictionary:

```
return render(request, "my_room.html", {
    'room_user': room_user,
}
```

Then, in your template, you'll want to build a nested `for` loop:

```
{% for room in room_user %}
    {% for rmessage in room.messages.all()[:1] %}
        <p>{{ rmessage.client }} : {{ rmessage.message }}</p>
        <p>{{ rmessage.timestamp }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```